# Given a function parameter of type [Int]; can it be constrained to not be empty?

Tags: swift

Please consider the following:

```
func example(array: [Int]) {
    guard array.count > 0 else { return }

    // Do something
}
```

It would be nice to announce the restriction via the function signature. Is it possible to constrain the parameter? Something equivalent to:

```
func example(array: [Int] where array.count > 0) {
    // Do something
}
```

Going one step further: let's make the array optional:

```
func example(array: [Int]?) {
    guard array == nil || array!.count > 0 else { return }

    // Do something
}

func example(array: [Int]? where array.count > 0) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: No, conditions are not possibly to include in the function signatures. Speculating wildly: but allowing such conditionals would possibly allow hacks that don't really go in line with Swifts strong typing. Note that your 2nd example would probably read better as `guard let array = array, array.count > 0 else { return }`.

Comment: The compiler does not know how many elements the array has at runtime.

Comment: Thx, @dfri
BTW: note that my guard allows the array to be nil, yours does not.

Comment: @RobertVaessen Ah, I was too quick there, my bad. I assumed you wanted to `return` if the array was either `nil` or, in case of non-`nil`, empty (but I see now you allow a `nil` array to pass through).

Comment: Ahhh, you are right, @Martin R. Constraints are applied at compile time. Good catch.

Comment: Another example to the `nil` or non-empty conditional in the 2nd example is: `guard !(array?.isEmpty ?? false) else { return }`, possibly likewise complex semantically, but avoiding the forced unwrap operator `!` (which I believe should be avoided even if we know the optional to be unwrapped to be non-`nil`: future small changes in your code e.g. by collegues might break such code parts into runtime errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't have a conditional parameter.  The best you can do is what you have in the second option with an optional and before you call the function (or posibly in the function) check if it is nil.