# How can I enforce a constrained input on callers of a function?

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, assert

A simplified version of my function is something like:

```
func addnumbers(_ number: Int, to number2: Int) -> Int{
    return number + number2

}
```

Yet I don't want any developer in our team to call with this function with a number greater than 3000.

So if another developer runs this with:

```
addNumbers(5 to:3) // good
addNumbers(5 to:4000) // compiler error/warning/popup
```

Is there anyway that I can enforce such?

The other way around it is to crash or throw an error/assert if another developer runs it a number more than 3000, but I want to do it one step sooner. (I don't want it to be a warning, I want it to be an error)

Comment: But what if it's called like `addNumbers(5 to: i)` where `i` isn't known until runtime?

Comment: Somewhat related: [Given a function parameter of type \[Int\]; can it be constrained to not be empty?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40323966/2976878)

Comment: @Hamish good point, does that enforcing a warning for: `addNumbers(5 to:4000)` is undoable?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was subtly getting at ;) There's no way for the compiler to know the value of the argument being passed in all circumstances, therefore it's impossible to guarantee that method parameter will be within a custom range without doing a runtime check for it. I don't *believe* there's any clever trickery you can do with literals either in order to get an error in the case of passing a given integer literal out of your custom range.